# Executing thread "one by one"

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a singleton class that n threads can access.
Each thread loads the instance of this class and invoke a method from this class in a loop.

I must control the flow of the execution so every thread can invoke the method one and pause, only after all thread invoked the method once the must resume their work. 
Threads can call method in any order, just all of them have to execute method once before moving the loop.

This what I tried to  do:

In thread:

```
 while ( some condition){
    ObjectType obj = theSingleton.getInstance().getSharedObject();
    obj.SomeMethod(threadID);
   if (obj.waitisneeded())
    synchronized (obj ) {
       obj.wait();
    }
}
```

what I did in  SomeMethod:

```
public  synchronized void SomeMethod(String threadID) {
 hashMap.put(threadID,true);
 some job here
}
```

and in waitisneeded:

```
public  synchronized boolean waitisneeded(){
{

   Iterator iter = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();

   boolean alldone = false;

   while (iter.hasNext()) { 
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
      String key = me.getKey().toString();
      alldone = (Boolean)me.getValue();

      if(!alldone)  {
    return false;
       }
   }

  //set all values to false 
 iter = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext()) { 
   Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    String key = me.getKey().toString();
   me.setValue(false);      
 }      
 this.notifyAll();
 return true;
```

Running this got me unexpected results and deadlocks.

How can I fix it?

Note: I can't change how the thread is created, I can only change those methods!!! (plus the while loop in the thread where wait is)

Comment: Do you know how many threads are created before each one calls `obj.SomeMethod()`?

Comment: How do you know when the point that "all expected threads have now called singleton" has been reached?

Comment: @TheScrumMeister Scrum Meister yes, i know the number of threads

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, as you can see in the code there is a hashmap in  getSharedObject , where I flag the thread that accessed it. when all threads checked i want to release the threads and cleare the hashmap so they can start all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the number of threads, you can use a [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

```
static final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(numberOfThreads);
```

Then, at the point in which you want to make all threads wait for the others, you call:

```
barrier.await();
```

If there's a thread that has not yet arrived at that line, the thread calling `await()` will block. Once all the threads arrive there and call `await()`, they will all resume.

Every time you must build some synchronization mechanism, be sure to check the package [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). There are lots of wonderful classes over there, created by experts. Most of the time you won't need something custom, and if you do, there are some classes in the same package that will make it almost unecessary to use wait/notify directly -- and, believe me, you want to avoid using these methods directly; as you can see, you can very easily get yourself into a deadlock!

Comment: I think there is a problem with CyclicBarrier, since the var is static. In my application this scenario can happen several times in parallel! X threads (i forgot to mention), getSharedObject is is generated and stored in singleton's hashmap variable. so every group of threads access their own object. this why I tried to use lock, and getSharedObject it self as the LOCK!  if I use static i would have to create new variable for every getSharedObject

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how your application works. I'm sure you can adapt to your scenario! The whole idea is that the threads that must wait for each other before resuming must share a single CyclicBarrier. Be sure to properly publish the barriers though! (that is, since you will have many CyclicBarriers, you'd better use a concurrent collection to hold the instances, such as ConcurrentHashMap).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical multithreading situation called Rendez-Vous (a french word meaning "appointment"). Basically your `N` threads will have an appointment and should all wait at a point until all of them reach it. As @Bruno mentioned, you can use a `CyclicBarrier` object to manage the situation. In case your scenario is run only once then you could also use a `CountDownLatch`.

Here is how you can achieve this:

```
static final CountDownLatch rendezVousPoint = new CountDownLacth(numberOfThreads);

//Every thread does the following right before waiting on the rendez vous point
rendezVousPoint.countDown();
rendezVousPoint.await();
```

In this situation, every thread will block on `await()` method until the last thread arrives and releases all of them (`rendezVousPoint` count reaches 0)

Comment: I'm not sure I like this (ab)use of `CountDownLatch`. You are subverting a `CountDownLatch`, making it behave exactly like a `CyclicBarrier` (which has been built to handle this very scenario). The methods `CDL.countDown()` and `CDL.await()`, called as you did, behave mostly like `CB.await()`, but they are 2 methods for a purpose (which is not being called one right after the other): usually, worker threads will call `CDL.countDown()` and only a master thread will call `CDL.await()`, in order to block until all the worker threads finished their tasks.

Comment: @BrunoReis Thanks for the comment, I tend to disagree with you on this. As per the official java documentation, there is nothing wrong with doing a `CDL.countDown()` and `CDL.await()` one after the other. A `CyclicBarrier` (as per the documentation) is a reusable (can be set and reset several times) version of a `CountDownLatch`